# Permission denied while getting the md5sum of a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hashsum

I am running my below shell script which gets the md5sum of a files in my PRIMARY directory

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/data01/primary

for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    local_md5sum=/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}'
    echo local_md5sum
done
```

As soon as I run above shell script and try to print out the md5sum value of my files, I always get -

```
./md5checksum_check_1.sh: line 7: /test01/prime/pp_monthly_1980_58_200003_5.data: Permission denied
```

But if I try to run the below command as it is on the console then it works fine -

```
/usr/bin/md5sum /test01/prime/pp_monthly_1980_58_200003_5.data | awk '{print $1}'
```

I am not sure why? Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Are you running your script under `cron`? If so, then perhaps the user under which it's running does not have permission to read your data file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25710660/3776858.

Comment: @GregHewgill No I am not running my script under cron. I am running as the same user which has the file permissions as well.

Comment: Ok. Are you running with [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) enabled?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 if that's what you meant?

Comment: SELinux is a kernel module that may be enabled in your distribution. Run `getenforce` to find out.

Comment: Oh, the answer is a lot simpler than I was imagining. Not really anything to do with file permissions, but just an error in your script.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need the for loop (unless you have a large number of files). `md5sum "$PRIMARY"/* | awk '{ print $1 }'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some syntax on this line:

```
local_md5sum=/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}'
```

You need

```
local_md5sum=$(/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
```

Without the `$()`, you are trying to *execute* `$entry` as a command.